# scrolling to an element failed in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

[image]I am working on Firstcry .com website for automation. After searched for Shoes int he search box, I need to scroll down to the bottom of the page to click "View All products" link. BUt scrolling is not happening.. what should be done... attached my code and screenshot for reference..

```
[public void f(String s) {
        String ExpecTitle = "Kids Footwear - Buy Baby Booties, Boys Shoes, Girls Sandals Online India";
        Actions builder = new Actions(Driver);
        Driver.get("https://www.firstcry.com/");
        String Viewall = "/html/body/div\[6\]/div\[2\]/div\[2\]/div\[2\]/div\[8\]/div\[2\]/span/a";
        String MainTitle = Driver.getTitle();
         System.out.println("Main title is " + MainTitle);
        
        WebElement SearchBox =  Driver.findElement(By.id("search_box"));
        SearchBox.clear();
        WebElement SearchBox2 =  Driver.findElement(By.id("search_box"));
        SearchBox2.sendKeys(s);
      //    SearchBox.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
        //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(Driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".search-button"))));
        Driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".search-button")).click();
        
        
        String ActTitle = Driver.getTitle();
         System.out.println("The page title is " + ActTitle);
         Driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
         if(ActTitle.contains("Kids Footwear")){
                      
             System.out.println("Inside the if condition");  
             js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
             WebElement viewALL = Driver.findElement(By.xpath(Viewall));
            // js.executeScript("arguments\[0\].scrollIntoView();", viewALL);
            
             Driver.findElement(By.xpath(Viewall)).click();
             
             System.out.println("View");  
             // WebElement viewAll = Driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div\[6\]/div\[2\]/div\[2\]/div\[2\]/div\[8\]/div\[2\]/span/a"));
             // js.executeScript("arguments\[0\].scrollIntoView(true);", viewAll);
             // wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a\[contains(text(),'View All Products')\]")));
             // viewAll.click();
          }
          
              WebElement element = Driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".sort-select-content"));
              element.click();
              builder.moveToElement(element).perform();
            
            {
              WebElement elem = Driver.findElement(By.linkText("Price"));
           elem.click();
            //  builder.moveToElement(elem).perform();
            }
            //Driver.findElement(By.linkText("Price")).click();
  }][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code worked for me:

```
    WebDriver Driver = new ChromeDriver();
    Driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Driver.manage().window().maximize();
    String url = "https://www.firstcry.com/";
    Driver.get(url);
    WebElement searchbox=Driver.findElement(By.id("search_box"));
    searchbox.clear();
    searchbox.sendKeys("shoes");
    Driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div/div[2]/form/span")).click();
    WebElement Element=Driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("View All Products"));
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) Driver;
    js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,document.body.scrollHeight)");
    Element.click();
```

Comment: thank you it works.. I just removed the extra click on line 9...

Answer (score 1):

After searching for Shoes in the search box and selecting the first suggestion, to scroll down to the bottom of the page to click on the element with text as **View All Products** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
driver.get("https://www.firstcry.com/");
WebElement searchBox = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='search_box']")));
searchBox.clear();
searchBox.sendKeys("Shoes");
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@id='searchlist']/ul/li/span"))).click();
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[text()='View All Products']"))));
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[text()='View All Products']"))).click();
```

Comment: Thank you..it works but I cannot add extra click in order to do the sorting.. its the instructions based execution...

Comment: @JeyanthiRanjit That seems to be a different usecase altogether. Can you raise a new question as per your new requirement please?

Answer (score 0):

// following code to scroll until element is visible and click that element

```
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;


    WebElement viewALL = Driver.findElement(By.xpath(Viewall));

            
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", viewALL);
     viewALL.click();
}
```

}

Comment: sorry but for some reason, its not scrolling to the element this way...I tried, but thanks for the time spent